# How to query certain jsonb fields using Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm trying to map a query like this using a jsonb column in Postgres into a C# object:

```
select item_object->'thing' 
FROM "Table", jsonb_array_elements("JsonColumn") 
with ordinality arr(item_object);
```

(Where in this case JsonColumn contains an array of JSON objects, each of which has a 'thing' field.)

I see that using JsonDocument or POCO can be used to map these Json functions in the WHERE clause, but in my case I'm trying to restrict how much of the document gets sent back to reduce the size and amount of deserialization needs to happen. Is there any way to do this in C# or do I need to build customized queries?

Thanks!

-- Edit --

For example, can we query specific jsonb fields using this sort of query in C#

```
DataContext.Table.Select(t => new { t.JsonColumn.thing });
```

To dig through the json and only return the 'thing' field instead of the entire json blob.

From the docs, this works in the Where clause:

```
var joes = context.CustomerEntries
    .Where(e => e.Customer.Name == "Joe")
    .ToList();
```

https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco

Comment: Please provide [mre]

Comment: There is nothing to reproduce. I'm wondering if this is a feature available with Npgsql.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can drill into JSON documents in Select just like in Where. In general, expressions which are supported in the latter work also in the former.

Comment: Thanks - is there documentation for this? Does it call the relevant Postgres JSON functions? For example, I would want the resulting query to look something like this:

`select value->'thing' FROM "FeatureSpecs", jsonb_array_elements("TypeDefinitions")`

I'm having trouble working out what the syntax should look like on the C# side so I can't run these queries to see if the resulting Psql queries are correct.

Comment: The supported translations related to JSON are in the docs: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#querying-json-columns.

Comment: The provider doesn't translate to json_array_elements because it *generally* doesn't make too much sense... I don't quite understand from your top query above what exactly you're trying to achieve - providing the full SQL which you want to get may help (or more details).

Comment: So as an example, is there a way to generate a query that would only return the Price field from the Orders array in the documentation linked to avoid having to return and deserialize ShippingAddress? I have a similar structure to this, but my equivalent to “ShippingAddress” could be quite large and for some performance sensitive queries I only need “Price”. I was able to write the query above using json_array_elements to make rows from which I could pull a single field to achieve this on the Postgres side, but was wondering if there was a way to generate something similar in EF.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info - no, I don't think that's currently possible to express in LINQ.. You'll have to use [raw SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) (but can still use EF to materialize the results, and even compose LINQ on top of the raw SQL).

Comment: That was my backup plan, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious. Thanks!